# SendMail - How to change recipient address's domain

Tags: linux, sendmail

I'm sending e-mails to an e-mail address from our network (let's call it recipient@br.domain.com) using `sendmail`. The output message in that machine shows the recipient as "ok" and shows that the message is being sent to that e-mail address, but when we see our smtp hub server, the request arrives as to send the message to recipient@domain.com (missing the "br."), so the message never arrives.

It seems like `sendmail` is replacing from whatever domain I indicate for the recipient to the machine's subdomain name (`$m` which is, indeed, "domain.com").

Is there anyway I can prevent `sendmail` from replacing the recipient e-mail domain?

I've got sendmail version: 8.14.7. The O.S. is a Linux Red Hat distribution, version 7.9.

Comment: When you write "_SendMail_" do you mean a command or tool that's capitalised like that or do you mean the `sendmail` command? If it's the second then which Mail Transport Agent (MTA) are you using to implement `sendmail`?

Comment: I mean sendmail command (I guess). The Linux sendmail service (/etc/mail/)

Comment: This is not a standard behavior; I'm guessing your local admin has broken the rules.

Comment: No point guessing, as the configuration files vary depending on the answer. Does `sendmail -v` or `sendmail --version` or `sendmail -V` shed any light on the matter? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/730306/edit) to provide the information (and fix "_SendMail_" to match reality, while you're there).

Comment: It would be helpful for you to tell us the Linux distribution or UNIX version too, as that often has relevance in this kind of situation

Comment: sendmail version: 8.14.7
The O.S. is a Red Hat distribution, version 7.9.

Comment: @roaima. I'm not familiar with Linux (total newbee here), but I'll be straight this time: it's not some tool, it's the sendmail service located on /etc/mail. I can share the files sendmail.mc, genericstable, generics-domains etc. if you need.

Comment: For me, no thank you. I haven't configured original `sendmail` probably for over 25 years. Hopefully someone else will be able to help you here. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I came here having the same problem.

Mails addressed to user@domain1 were changed to user@domain2.

In my case the domain1 and domain2 were hosted on the same machine/mail server. That machine's regular hostname is domain2 while domain1 is "only" a DNS alias to domain2.
Apparantly sendmail does a reverse lookup on the to-address and changes that address to whatever comes up as basis DNS entry.

My solution:
It may not be the best approach, but I added an entry to the sending machine's /etc/hosts file that says:
 domain2 domain1

While that entry is active mails to user@domain1 are being correctly transmitted.

So in your case do your domains happen to resolve to the same IP address?